# No answers on meta questions, only votes!

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, meta

I am a new participant on meta.stackoverflow.com.

I've observed that **typically all questions on meta site have a lot of upvotes or downvotes, but don't have answers**. Few that do have answers, have like 1 or 2 answers.

Interestingly most people comment.

I am worried and anxious to understand **why is this?**

- Are we, the meta site participants, wary of answering questions on meta site?
- Do we prefer that only moderators should answer questions posted here?
- Are we afraid that answers may get too much downvotes or do we see answers as a gateway to arguments with people doling out aggressive/opinionated comments. I feel most questions simply invite an opinion (like those tagged as '[feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request)') or tries to validate the opinion of asker of question.
- Are the questions being posted on the site are usually the one's which have been debated and gilded in past and most of us usually think there is no need to answer them again?

Keeping in mind this type of situation should the meta site be converted from Q&A type format to something else like a blog post or forum format?

Below is the screen shot of what I see on questions tab :

[image]

Comment: Have you read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta? Also, I feel like you're somewhat cheating by *using the Unanswered tab*...

Comment: Aren't you on the wrong tab?

Comment: There are currently [1612 questions with 3 or more answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+answers%3A3..). I'm not sure what you are worried about, why are more answers good? Sure, there are 3943 questions with 0 answers, and 9544 questions with 1 or 2 answers. Meta is just a different beast, most questions can be answered rather straightforwardly, and don't *need* more answers.

Comment: It still takes effort to answer questions (for reasons I don't feel like expanding on right now).  Better to leave a comment than than incomplete answer.

Comment: Running an [answers:0](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0) query yields 3,943 questions with no answers out of 15,099 questions on Meta. That's 26% of Meta questions, which is a far cry from "typically all".

Comment: @jonrsharpe I agree about making it over the top by posting from unanswered tab. But there are so many votes. If people can write comments and vote a question, can't we phrase an answer

Comment: My vote for posting such a big screenshot here!

Comment: Probably because they didn't use a ginormous screenshot.

Comment: @BradLarson  I changed the answers to 1 and it brings 11,156 results. this is 73% .

Comment: @DruvJoshi indeed... answers:1 means that it has AT LEAST one answer. If 26% have no answer, what did you expect to get with "questions with at least one answer?" :P

Comment: @DhruvJoshi: so 7.2k questions got answered on the first try, almost half of all questions posted. 11.2k have 1 or more answers, so 70% or so has an answer. Yay us! Why, again, is this a problem? More answers does not mean more quality, necessarily. And [1098 of those 0-answer questions are closed as duplicates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+duplicate%3Ayes+answers%3A0..0), a handful more for other reasons.

Comment: @BradLarson Also, 1,098 of those are closed as duplicates - so they may still be answered, just not in that spot.

Comment: @Patrice Mea Culpa! New to this. So I changed the query. This https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+answers%3A0.1 should probably give correct result

Comment: @DruvJoshi depending on what you want to see, yes :P. In any case, meta being so different, I wouldn't worry with those numbers here

Comment: Why are we discussing this? Go answer those question instead...

Comment: Conclusion : So I guess `Meta` is special and votes are a better indicator on meta.

Comment: Yikes..would be a good idea to edit that screenshot out. What a mess

Comment: @Trobbins why? Are you jealous that I'm in the screenshot and you're not ... ;)

Comment: @rene What are you talking about? displayName is clearly on there. :l

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On Meta sometimes you only need to vote to convey an opinion. Feature requests, bug reports and even some discussions can often be more or less answered with a vote.

It boils down to "I think this is a good idea..." or "I don't think this is a good idea..."

With feature requests this logic is usually pretty clear. On bug reports it can be as simple as "I can/can't see said problem too." Discussions can be a little less clear, It is usually more of an "I agree/disagree with the sentiment or premise of this post..."

This being the case not all questions need answers that simply say:
"I agree/disagree with the problem/solution presented in the question..."

---

With all of that said, I could have just downvoted this question to indicate that I thought the premise of the question was flawed and that there wasn't a real problem to solve.

Comment: A vote without a voice is just an opinion in its most base form. Polls are significantly better as they a) show the absolute number cast, and b) ask a specific question. Voting on meta is pretty meaningless, and outside the context of feature discussion, is pointless.